# Exporting both functions and types in a typescript library

Tags: typescript

`typescript: 5.0.2`

I'm trying to create a typescript library where I can export both the utility functions and the internal types the library uses. I can export the functions just fine. But for the life of me, I can't export the types for others to use.

My directory structure is pretty simple:

```
my-library/
├─ dist/
│  ├─ a.js
│  ├─ b.js
│  ├─ index.js
│  ├─ index.d.ts
│  ├─ a.d.ts
|  └─ b.d.ts
├─ src/
│  ├─ a.ts
│  ├─ b.ts
│  ├─ index.ts
│  └─ types/
│     ├─ a.d.ts
│     └─ b.d.ts
├─ package.json
└─ tsconfig.json
```

The index.ts imports everything from module a and b.

index.ts

```
export * from './a'
export * from './b'
```

And for simplicity, let's assume a and b only export one thing each. And their type files only export one thing each.

a.ts

```
import { FooFunction } from './types/a'
export foo : FooFunction = () => 'Foo'
export type * from './types/a // For hopefully re-exporting the types in index.ts
```

a.d.ts

```
export type FooFunction = () => 'string'
```

b.ts

```
import { BarFunction } from './types/a'
export bar : BarFunction = () => 'Bar'
export type * from './types/b // For hopefully re-exporting the types in index.ts
```

b.d.ts

```
export type BarFunction = () => 'string'
```

I have `declaration: true` set in the tsconfig so I get the types output into the dist folder. And I have `main: "dist/index.js"` and `types: "dist/index.d.ts` in the `package.json` so other projects can import the utility functions.

My goal is that another project can have something like this:

```
import { foo, FooFunction } from 'my-library'
```

The type signature for `foo` comes through just fine. But `FooFunction` is not available. I looked around and only saw answers regarding the `module` and `namespace` keyword. Is there a more modern pattern for this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution was to not use `.d.ts` files or a types folder. If I include all of the types and interfaces into a.ts and b.ts and then export them from there, they will be picked up in the `export *` in index.ts and exported correctly.

For some reason, the paths to the `.d.ts` file are included in the built files in the dist folder and no longer resolve. I'm assuming it's because of those broken paths that my original directory structure doesn't work.

Comment: For what it's worth, the way you were using declaration files is very unconventional and highly confusing. You're also misusing type only exports

Comment: What's the convention?